# How can I merge two columns in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm using the dataframe *sheep.df* from *dmm* library in R.

```
sheep.df <- data.frame(
  Id = factor(c(
    "9a4003", "0a4721", "1a4123", "1a4371", "2a4127", "9a4071",
    "9a4123", "9a4062", "0a4712", "0a4781", "0a4441", "1a4128", "1a4127",
    "1a4129", "2a4242", "2a4243", "2a4244", "2a4245", "2a4246", "3a4127",
    "3a4128", "3a4129", "3a4140", "3a4141", "3a4142", "3a4143", "4a4144",
    "4a4145", "4a4146", "4a4117", "4a4118", "4a4119", "5a4129", "5a4140",
    "5a4141", "6a4242", "6a4243", "6a4244", "6a4245", "6a4246", "7a4127",
    "7a4128"
  )),
  SId = factor(c(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "9a4003",
    "9a4003", "9a4003", "9a4003", "9a4003", "0a4721", "0a4721", "1a4123",
    "1a4123", "1a4123", "1a4371", "1a4371", "2a4127", "2a4127", "2a4127",
    "2a4127", "2a4127", "2a4127", "1a4123", "1a4123", "1a4123", "9a4003",
    "9a4003", "9a4003", "9a4003", "9a4003", "0a4721", "0a4721"
  )),
  DId = factor(c(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "9a4123",
    "9a4123", "9a4062", "9a4071", "9a4071", "0a4712", "0a4713", "1a4128",
    "1a4127", "1a4127", "1a4129", "2a4243", "2a4244", "2a4246", "2a4247",
    "3a4127", "3a4128", "3a4129", "1a4128", "1a4127", "1a4127", "9a4123",
    "9a4123", "9a4062", "9a4071", "9a4071", "0a4712", "0a4713"
  )),
  Year = factor(c(
    "1981", "1982", "1983", "1983", "1984", "1981", "1981", "1981",
    "1982", "1982", "1982", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1984", "1984",
    "1984", "1984", "1984", "1985", "1985", "1986", "1986", "1986",
    "1986", "1986", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1988", "1988", "1988",
    "1987", "1987", "1987", "1985", "1985", "1985", "1985", "1985",
    "1986", "1986"
  )),
  Tb = factor(c(
    "S", "S", "S", "T", "S", "S", "S", "T", "S", "S", "T", "S",
    "T", "T", "T", "T", "S", "T", "T", "S", "S", "S", "T", "T", "S",
    "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", NA, "S", "S", "T", "T", "T", "T", "S",
    "T", "T", "S", "S"
  )),
  Sex = factor(c(
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F",
    "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M",
    "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F",
    "M", "F", "M", "F"
  )),
  Cww = c(
    NA, NA, NA, 4.2, 4.7, 4.1, 4.4, 3.8, 5.1, 4.9, 4.6, 4.1, 3.9, 4.6, 4.4, 4.1,
    4.4, 4.8, 5.2, 5.7, 5, 4.7, 5.6, 5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.1, 3.9, 4.5, NA, 4.1, NA, 4.7,
    5.6, 5, 4.4, 4.1, 4.4, 4.8, 5.2, 5.7, 5
  ),
  Diam = c(
    NA, NA, NA, 21.7, 21.1, 20, 21.6, 20.1, 22, 21.1, 20.8, 20.3, 19.1, 19.8,
    19.2, 19.8, 19.9, 20.2, 21.1, 22.1, 21.9, 22.1, 22, 21.1, 22, 19.8, 20.3,
    19.1, 20.5, NA, 19.1, 19.6, 22.1, 22, 21.1, 19.2, 19.8, 19.9, 20.2, 21.1,
    22.1, 21.9
  ),
  Bwt = c(
    NA, NA, NA, 50, 45, 51, 53, 43, 45, 48, 49, 48, 42, 44, 40, 41, 45, 47, 49,
    53, 50, 38, 51, 39, 53, 37, 39, 36, 45, NA, 36, 38, 38, 51, 39, 40, 41, 45,
    47, 49, 53, 50
  )
)
```

What I would line to obtain is a new data frame where `Sid` and `Did` columns are merged into a new column `Parent`. So, for each row of the original data frame there will be two new rows in the new data frame with same `Id` value.

Example:

Original row `(id1, sid1, did1)`

New rows `(id1, sis1), (id1, did1)`.

I hope I made it clear, otherwise let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear how you want your output. Also how do you want to handle the NAs?

Comment: Try with `library(tidyr);sheep.df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(SId, DId))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extremely confusing question, but a best attempt to answer:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dmm)

data("sheep.df")

Original_row <- sheep.df %>% 
                dplyr::select(Id, SId, DId)
New_rows <- Original_row %>% 
            pivot_longer(cols = c("SId", "DId"))
```

A subset of the result:

```
  Id     name  value 
  <fct>  <chr> <fct> 
1 6a4246 SId   9a4003
2 6a4246 DId   9a4071
3 7a4127 SId   0a4721
4 7a4127 DId   0a4712
5 7a4128 SId   0a4721
6 7a4128 DId   0a4713
```